# Joomla 4 - Subcategory title in category blog

Tags: joomla-4.x, category-blog, cassiopeia

I am using a Category Blog to show items from 2 categories using the subcategory option.

Cat 1
---- article 1
---- article 2
---- article 3

Cat 2
---- article 1
---- article 2
---- article 3

All of the items are successfully being rendered on the page BUT there is no Category title ("Cat1" & "Cat2")? Am I missing something here in the settings or is really not an option!?

Comment: Hello j00m, In order to get the best answer for your question please expand on it a bit more. What version of Joomla are you currently using and what settings have you tried to change so far to accomplish what you are looking to do?

Comment: The title of the question says Joomla 4. Ive tried to change all settings in the Category blog section but doesnt seem to be an option to output the category title? It just pumps out all the items.

Comment: sorry I missed that in the title. From what experimenting I have done it doesn't appear that there is a list layout for the Category menu item. The easy solution would probably be to create a layout override in your template to generate the exact display that you want.